# Is there a more efficient way to do a one-to-many relationship than having the "one" value in every row returned?

Tags: database, postgresql, join, database-design, one-to-many

I have a pretty basic one-to-many relationship. There are "nodes", and each node relates to multiple "options". I am doing a fairly simple join, and my results are like this:

```
           content        | optionid |     content      
--------------------------+----------+------------------
 This is the node content |        1 | This is option 1
 This is the node content |        2 | This is option 2
```

However, because it's one-to-many, every row has the same node content: `This is the node content`. It seems redundant to return that same value with every row when I only need it once. Is there a better way?

Comment: There are quite a lot of different [aggregate functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-aggregate.html) you could use. For example `json(b)_object_agg` could work for you nicely if `optionid` is unique.

Comment: Is the redundancy causing you harm?  For example, is it slowing you down?

Comment: @Sevanteri Thank you for telling me about that! `jsonb_object_agg` does exactly what I wanted. If you post that as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `jsonb_object_agg` 
[aggregate function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-aggregate.html)
seems like a good choice for this.

```
SELECT
    n.content,
    jsonb_object_agg(o.optionid, o.content)
FROM node n
JOIN option o ON (
    -- what ever are the conditions
)
GROUP BY n.content;
```

Comment: I think json (text format) is preferable to jsonb (binary format), but good answer.

Comment: It depends. If you're always going to select the whole JSON then yes it might be better to use JSON instead of JSONB. And yea, in this case it actually might be better.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is how relational databases work - you have to do compromises.

If you think this query generates too large data flow between application server and the database, you could split it in two queries. Load the `content` separately and then load `options` avoiding the redundancy. This could also have a performance benefit (less memory, no JOIN, etc).

On the other hand, this has latency due to separate queries being run. Especially in looped queries this can be notably slower. So, it's all about compromises.